# Python BST Range Sum Function Not Returning Expected Results Will Using Local Variable

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, local-variables

I'm currently working on a Python function that's supposed to calculate the sum of values in a Binary Search Tree (BST) within a given range. However, my code doesn't seem to be working as expected. I'd appreciate some guidance on what might be going wrong.

Here's the code for the `Solution` class I'm using:

```py
class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root, low: int, high: int) -> int:
        def dfs(root):
            if root is None:
                return 0
            c = 0
            if low <= root.val <= high:
                c += root.val
            dfs(root.left)
            dfs(root.right)
            return c
        return dfs(root)
```

The idea is to perform a Depth-First Search (DFS) on the BST and add values to the sum `c` if they fall within the given range (`low` to `high`). However, it's not returning the correct result.

I've tried to debug this code, but I can't figure out what's causing the issue. Is there something obvious I'm missing in my implementation, or is there a logical error in my code that's leading to incorrect results?

Any help or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling `dfs` but not doing anything with the returning values. You should add them to the sum instead:

```
class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root, low: int, high: int) -> int:
        def dfs(root):
            if root is None:
                return 0
            c = dfs(root.left) + dfs(root.right)
            if low <= root.val <= high:
                c += root.val
            return c
        return dfs(root)
```